# Control Panel PHP Error

Tags: control-panel

I am getting the following error when I go to the My Account section in the CP and click on Edit Profile. It's preventing me from saving my updates.

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined offset: 0
Filename: cp/myaccount.php
Line Number: 349

**EE 2.7.2**

**Modules:**

Calendar 1.8.6

Channel Images 5.4.12

Forum 3.1.13

Facebook Connect 2.1.3

Freeform Pro 4.1.3

Importer 2.2.3

Mailing List 1.0

Pages 2.2

Postmaster 1.4.7

Super Search 2.1.3

User 3.4.5

Wygwam 3.2.1

**Extensions (not listed in Modules)**

Matrix

Playa

Resource Router

Stash

**FieldTypes (not listed above)**

CKI Member List

VMG Chosen Member

Comment: You'll need to provide more information for anyone to be able to help, starting with which version of EE, what add-ons you have installed, etc.

Comment: Good point. Ive updated the post to include that info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line 349 is trying to get the first result from the query to get the member_data for that user.  It appears as if you will see this error any time you try to edit a member that does not exist.

Comment: Hi Steve, I took a look at the database and even though I am in the exp_members table there is no record for my user in exp_member_data table. Not sure how it happened but it looks like that was the issue. Thank you.